# jQuery selector not selecting

Tags: jquery

I am unable to get this event to fire:

```
  $("#about").click(function()
  {  //I have put alert("foo") here, won't fire
    $("#about_stuff").toggle();
  });
```

snip

```
   <li ><a href="#a" id="about">About</a>
```

I've tested the toggle line in Firebug and it successfully works - I am at my wits end, I've checked it against multiple examples and it persistently refuses to work.

Comment: just out of curiousity, why are you using `href="#a"` instead of `href="#"`?

Comment: @Alastair: so I know that I hit the right link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code:
First, you have `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(
  function()
  { // <-- start ready
  $("code").hide();
  }); // <-- end ready
```

Now, the following code isn't in `document.ready`, and written before the links have loaded. This is why the selector is empty when this code runs:

```
  $("#about").click(
  function()
  {  
  $("#about_stuff").toggle();
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - does the selector code have to be assigned during document.ready?

Comment: Yes, it does. Your `<script>` is written before the `<a>` tag - `#about` doesn't exist yet when the code runs.

Comment: Interesting! Well, it works. I'll have to rummage up a readable summary of the DOM model. Thanks!

Comment: Probably a good idea to move your js down the page too... it'll slow down the page load while the javascript executes.

Comment: Oh wow. I just assumed when I read it that it was in the document ready block

Answer (score 0):

Do you by chance have another element with `id="about"` assigned to it? If so, the browser may only select the first. Try a few basic diagnostics:

```
alert($('#about').length);
alert($('#about').eq(0).attr('href'));
```

If still no joy, do you have a link to the dev site, or is it private?

Comment: Nope - just checked. Also, I've renamed it a few times, just to make sure no weirdness crept in.

Comment: Answers - "1", and "#a". (which is what I would expect, I think...)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5hyVrH2d here's a pastebin of a slightly redacted code- it'll die after a while. I'll edit the OP once I get the thingie sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#about").click(function(e){  
    e.preventDefault(); // to prevent default event
    $("#about_stuff").toggle();
});
```